# Animate a Path filling in - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-4.0

Given a closed Path of bezier curves, how would I go about animating it filling in.  The fill would have to be non-linear - flowing around an acute angle rather than just a plane uncovering the filled color.

At this point, I'm assuming I'd have to use a WriteableBitmap and do it all myself.  thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

A RadialBrush originating from the center and spreading outwards often looks acceptable. See the "Coloring Pages" section of the [Kinectimals](http://xbox.com/kinectimals) website for an example.

Another implementation that might work would be to apply the shape to the Path's Clip property, then animate the StrokeThickness property to a very large value.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="FillShape">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="118">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Path x:Name="path" Data="M118,128 C182,300 238,342 330,252 C422,162 358,-40.000271 270,37.999855 C182,115.99998 118,128 118,128 z" Margin="117.5,19.95,264.563,181.398" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" Clip="M0.4999969,108.05005 C64.500069,280.04974 120.50012,322.04968 212.50023,232.04984 C304.50034,142.04999 240.50026,-59.949921 152.50015,18.050066 C64.500069,96.050049 0.4999969,108.05005 0.4999969,108.05005 z" StrokeThickness="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Somehow I missed this comment, thanks for the ideas.  We ended up using a writable bitmap to get the effect we needed.